# calculate the cutoff frequency of a low pass filter

Tags: low-pass

[image]

Given that R = 12kΩ and C = 3.3nF, calculate the cutoff frequency (fc), unit in Hz.

The frequency response of Vo/Vi is 1/(1+j ω RC).
Therefore,cut off radian frequency(Wc) is equal to 1/RC. 
Then, cut off frequency  ω = ωc, isn't the frequency just the 1/RC which is equal to 25252.5252 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes
You must convert the units from cycles per second to radians per second using  ω = 2πf

or
 f=1/(2πRC)

as you have done.

But since component tolerances are rarely < 1% , prudent answers only use 3 sigfigs.

so 25.3kHz is close enough, otherwise you look like a rookie.

Answer (score 1):

For an RC filter, the cut-off frequency, in *radians per second*, is as you stated:

$$ω_c = \frac{1}{RC}$$

[As Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 mentioned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/365875/256752), the relationship between frequency \$ω\$ in \$\mathrm{rad/s}\$, and frequency \$f\$ in \$\mathrm{Hz}\$, is:

$$
ω = 2πf
$$

Substituting \$2πf_c\$ for \$ω_c\$ in the original equation gives:

$$2πf_c = \frac{1}{RC}$$

Solving for \$f_c\$, the cut-off frequency in *Hertz* is:

$$f_c = \frac{1}{2πRC}$$

With your resistance \$R = 12\mathrm{kΩ}\$ and capacitance \$C = 3.3\mathrm{nF}\$, this gives:

$$ω_c = \frac{1}{RC} = \frac{1}{(12\mathrm{kΩ})(3.3\mathrm{nF})} = 25\mathrm{krad/s}$$

$$f_c = \frac{1}{2πRC} = \frac{1}{2π(12\mathrm{kΩ})(3.3\mathrm{nF})} = 4.0\mathrm{kHz}$$